# How to get IntelliJ IDEA to show all resource bundle files

Tags: intellij-idea

How do you get IntelliJ IDEA (I'm using 2018.1 Community Edition) to show all of the language files for a resource bundle in the Project tool window?

I created one not long ago and added a second language (in addition to the default locale) and it was working fine (I could see them both). However, now that I've closed and reopened the IDE, all I can see is just one .properties file, and not the additional file for the second language. If I change my default locale in code, everything works as it should and the strings are used from the second language.

When I double click on the only .properties file that's visible (the resource bundle base name), I can edit the default locale, but the only way I can edit the second language file is by going outside the IDE to see the extra file.

I'm using macOS 10.13 High Sierra if that's relevant.

Comment: Looks like a bug. Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample to reproduce.

Comment: I was experimenting with resource bundles for internationalisation and the IDE seems to have made a mess of my .idea/resourceBundles.xml. I edited it manually and restarted the IDE, and it's showing the files properly. I'll see if I can recreate the steps, and if so, log a bug. Thanks CrazyCoder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The issue still existed after upgrading to version 2019.2

However, before finding the solution, I could workaround the issue by opening the secondary message file with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>.

**Investigation**

The file `./idea/resourceBundles.xml` only contains one file entry instead of several.

**Solution**

Inspired by the comment of Marc Fearby, I found a similar solution, but more radical.
To restore the visibility of all message*.properties files in "Resource Bundle 'messages'"

- *Delete* the file `./idea/resourceBundles.xml`
- Restart IntelliJ.

Both files message*.properties appeared again and the translation editor was activated again too.

**Last notes**

One thing to mention is that IntelliJ did not re-create the file. So it looks that it is created following some manual action.